# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

I've this complete error:

```js
(node:9352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Object.exports.run (C:\users\Cocoloco2005\Desktop\peterbot\commands\play.js:24:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
(node:9352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9352) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is an issue that happened to my creating my discord bot, with Discord.js, in the "play" command

(Full command here:

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
exports.run = async (client, message, args, ops) => {
    if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('Connectes toi à un salon vocal');


    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Entres une URL');
    let validate = await ytdl.validateURL(args[0]);
  
    

    if (!validate) {
      let commandFile = require('./search.js');
      return commandFile.run(client, message, args, ops);
    
    }

    let info = await  ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);

 let data = ops.active = (message.guild.id) || {};
    if (!data.connection) data.connection = await message.member.voiceChannel.join();
    if(!data.queue) data.queue = [];
    data.guildID = message.guild.id;

    data.queue.push[0]({
        songTitle: info.title,
        requester: message.author.tag,
        url: args[0],
        announceChannel: message.channel.id

    });

    if (!data.dispatcher) play(client, ops, data);
    else {
        message.channel.send(`Added to queue: ${info.title} | requested by: ${message.author.id}`)
    }
    ops.active.set(message.guild.id, data);


}
async function play(client, ops, data) {
    client.channels.get(data.queue[0].announceChannel).send(`Now Playing: ${data.queue[0].songTitle} | Requested by: ${data.queue[0].requester}`);

    data.dispatcher = await data.connection.playStream(ytdl(data.queue[0].url, {filter: 'audioonly'}));
    data.dispatcher.guildID = data.guildID;

    data.dispatcher.once('end', function() {
        end(client, ops, this);

    });

}
function end(client, ops, dispatcher){

    let fetched = ops.active.get(dispatcher.guildID);

    fetched.queue.shift();

    if (fetched.queue.length > 0) {
        ops.active.set(dispatcher.guildID, fetched);
        play(client, ops, fetched);
    } else {
        ops.active.delete(dispatcher.guildID);

        let vc = client.guilds.get(dispatcher.guildID).me.voiceChannel;  

        if (vc) vc.leave();

    }

}
```

I don't know what to do, I didn't try anything "especial" because I'm new with Javascript.
I tried to search but I don't find anything about people having my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in this block:

```
data.queue.push[0]({
    songTitle: info.title,
    requester: message.author.tag,
    url: args[0],
    announceChannel: message.channel.id

});
```

Unless `push` is an index-able property of `queue`, that first line is probably the issue. It seems to me that you might have accidentally added the `[0]`, since this would be a valid statement without it. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but the error stills there, I remember that i tried to put the `[0]` to fix the "Push error", thank you anyway !

Comment: Ps/Pd: The bot connects to the VoiceChannel, but he plays nothing, andddddd I have 2 more errors (I guess)   (node:9732) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9732) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: @Cocoloco Okay! Then my next assumption would be that the `data` variable value is not being assigned correctly. Could something be wrong in the line `let data = ops.active = (message.guild.id) || {};`?

Comment: I think that could be the `/* global Map*/
/* global client*/
const active = new Map();` In the server.js/index.js file, I needed to change the original code, that specifies the `ops active` o something like that, that could be?

Comment: Now I remember what i changed, that was the `let ops = {
 ownerID: ownerID,
 active: active
}`  part, `active: active`

Comment: @Cocoloco2005 Nop, I tried to put the `active: active`, but that's not important in the code, I still have the push error

Comment: @Cocoloco2005 Alright! If that's not the problem, then try examining what is happening to `data.queue` According to your error, `data.queue` is undefined. Try changing the if statement `if (!data.queue) ...` to `if (data.queue == null) ...`. I'm quite confident that this should fix it, if nothing else is wrong!